# creating static instance of a class

Tags: php, class, constants

I'm rather new in PHP and it turns out that I'm not able to find a solution for the following problem:

I have a simple class like this:

```
class User{

  private $name;

  function __construct($name){
    $this->name = $name;
  }
}
```

All I want to do is to define a static instance of it, like one of these:

```
public const UNKNOWN_USER = new User("unknown);
```

so that I can use this as a dummy everywhere, e.g.:

```
public static login($name){
  if( /* userdoesnotexist */ ){
    return UNKNOWN_USER;
  }
}
```

and check for it - of course:

```
if( login($name) == UNKNOWN_USER){
  /* I don't know you! */
}
```

---

I've tried the following:

```
$UNKNOWN_USER = new User("unknown");
/* $UNKNOWN_USER not available in class-methods */

define(UNKNOWN_USER, new User("unknown"));
/* not allowed */

class User{
  const UNKNOWN_USER = new User("unknown");
  /* "new" leads to a syntax error */
}
```

Comment: Have a look at the [null object pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Null_Object_pattern) as well, as that kind of seems to be what you are trying to achieve.

Comment: yes like @fireeyedboy noted a null object or just `null` would probably be a better return value. Because: What if there is a real user with name "unknown" and what happens if you call the login method of user "unknown"?

Comment: The null object pattern is indeed an interesting pattern which I do not know and the demur because of the the real user with the name "unknown" is definetly true. But I can deal with that design flaw in favour of better code-readability. I hate `null` as a return value and the login method is static , so it won't be called on the unknown_user :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For constants only scalar values are allowed (float, int, string, bool, NULL). But you can set your UNKNOWN-insatnce to a static class variable

```
class User{
  public static $unknown_user = NULL;
  ...
}

User::$unknown_user = new User("unknown");
```

and then user `User::$unknown_user` instead of `UNKNOWN_USER`.

Comment: very simple and clear answer. Exactly what I needed. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

You cannot use `const` for anything else then scalar types. That excludes any objects. What you are trying to achive here is to make an object [immutable](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Immutable_object). You can do this in many ways though they are nither simple nor straightforward. Take a look at the [Builder pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Builder_pattern) for instance. Another way would be to make the object *lockable*. But all of the *safe* methods to achieve this require some coding on your part.

The simplest lockable pattern for your example, that I can think of:

```
class User{

    private $name;

    private $is_locked = false;

    function __construct($name){
        $this->setName($name);
    }

    public function lock() {
        $this->is_locked = true;
    }

    public function getName() {
        return $this->name;
    }

    public function setName($name) {
        if ( $this->is_locked ) {
            throw new Exception("The object is locked");
        }
        $this->name = $name;
    }
}
```

Now you can do:

```
$user1 = new User("John");
$user1->setName("Johnny");
```

but after you lock the object, you can't manipulate it anymore:

```
$user1->lock();
$user1->setName("Big John"); // Exception thrown
```

Comment: My intention wasn't the immutability - sorry that this wasn't clear enough.

Comment: Ok, np. Just remember that static members are generally a [bad practice](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7026507/why-are-static-variables-considered-evil) :)

Comment: true, it would be better if it would be immutable, too.

Answer (score 0):

You can do that like this:

```
<?php 
//Normal UnknownUser singleton pattern
class UnknownUser {
    private static $instance;

    //define properties
    public $myproperty = "hiho123";        

    private function __construct() {

    }

    public static function getInstance() {
       if(empty($instance)) {
          self::instance = new UnknownUser();
       }
       return self::instance;
    }

    //Make the class constant
    function __set($name, $value) {
        throw new Exception("Can't set property: " . __CLASS__ . "->$name");
    }
}
```

You can call the `UnknownUser`, like this:

`$unknownUser = UnknownUser::getInstance();`

And this make this class global and constant, can not be modified, because the magic method `__set` is activated to disable editing the properties.